# How to handle the declaration and allocation of an array whose type is determined at runtime?

Tags: c, malloc, type-conversion

Suppose I have five binary files on disk. These five files encode sequences of numbers in a binary format except they all have different types. Let's say they are SHORT INT, INT, LONG, FLOAT, and DOUBLE. We'll let the files also have a different number of numbers stored in them.

Now suppose I have a program that when executed, asks the user

> Enter filename you wish to load:

and the user can pick one of these five files. I would like the program to load these files into an array so that further calculations may be performed.

We may assume there exist two functions: one that returns an integer value that encodes the type  (i.e., SHORT INT, INT, LONG, FLOAT, or DOUBLE) of the file (call it "getfiletype") and one that returns the number of numbers (e.g., 1000, 9338, 8131, 0, etc.) in the file (call it "getfilesize"). The actual number of entries may be billions of numbers large. If possible, within the program I would like to use the same name for the array (say "array") that holds the values of whatever file the user picked. That way I can have blocks like

```
N=getfilesize("pickedfile.dat");
for(i=0 ; i<N ; i++ ) {
    doublearray[i]==2.0*(double)array[i]+7.12;
}
```

that can transform the array. Here I have introduced a new array called "doublearray" to hold the transformed values. This double array would then either be written to a file in format DOUBLE or converted before write to one of the other formats.

How do I do this sort of thing? Throughly confused.

Comment: C is a statically typed language so you cannot declare a *type* at run-time.Types have to be specified at compilation.What you can have is a void pointer(`void *`) which can point to any data type.Ofcourse, You need to be careful while performing the required type casting.

Comment: You can't dynamically change the base type of arrays in C, it is not made for that. Basically you would have to write one function per type that you want to handle. You could help yourself in writing a macro that produces these 10 different functions, but this is nothing that you should to if you are a beginner with C. BTW your code snippet has a serious flaw already. Read it carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program could create a static (or global) void* array that would be populated by the latest call to either getfiletype() or getfilesize().  You would then have to appropriately cast it (as you've done specifically to double in your example).  It is assumed you've solved the loading of the file data aspect.

Although that approach is not really very clean in terms of usage (relying on a static or global would limit your options for performing different conversations - specifically as it currently stands you would have to ensure you operate in a sequential manner).

A cleaner API would perhaps be something along these lines:

```
enum TypeEnum { SHORT_INT, INT, LONG, FLOAT, DOUBLE };
void* getfiledata(char *filename, unsigned int *size, TypeEnum *type);
#define GET_DATA_AND_CAST(filename, array, array_size) \
    do { \
        TypeEnum type; \
        void* arr = getfiledata(filename, array_size, &type); \
        switch(type) { \
            case SHORT_INT: \
                array = (short*)arr; break; \
            case INT: \
                array = (int*)arr; break; \
            case LONG: \
                array = (long*)arr; break; \
            case FLOAT: \
                array = (float*)arr; break; \
            case DOUBLE: \
                array = (double*)arr; break; \
            default: \
                // ASSERT \
        } \
    } while(0)
```

You can then use it like:

```
void process_doubles(void *array) {
    double to_conv[];
    unsigned int size;
    GET_DATA_AND_CAST("pickedfile.dat", to_conv, &size);

    for(i=0; i<size; ++i ) {
        doublearray[i] = 2.0 * to_conv[i] + 7.12;
    }
}
```

IMHO C++ would make this even nicer (as you could use templates), but as this question is only tagged with C I'm just presenting options in C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `void *` pointer to store a pointer to any data type.

```
int num_elements = getfilesize();
size_t element_size;
switch (getfiletype()) {
    case SHORT_INT: element_size = sizeof(short int); break;
    ...
}
void *array = malloc(num_elements * element_size);

...

void process_doubles(void *array) {
    for(i=0 ; i<getfilesize("pickedfile.dat") ; i++ ) {
    doublearray[i] = 2.0 * ((double *) array)[i] +7.12;
}
```

Note that you need to cast the array pointer *before* indirecting it.